# Filter out DataFrame rows that have insufficient number of observations based on a column defining a category in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, counter

I have a `DataFrame` with a column that divides the data set into a set of categories. I would like to remove those categories that have a small number of observations.

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['c1', 'c2', 'c1', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c2'], 'v': [5, 2, 7, 1, 2, 8, 3]})

    c  v
0  c1  5
1  c2  2
2  c1  7
3  c3  1
4  c4  2
5  c5  8
6  c2  3
```

For column `c` and `n = 2`, remove all the rows that have less than `n` same values in column `c`, resulting in:

```
    c  v
0  c1  5
1  c2  2
2  c1  7
3  c2  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) followed by Boolean indexing via [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
counts = df['c'].value_counts()  # create series of counts
idx = counts[counts < 2].index   # filter for indices with < 2 counts

res = df[~df['c'].isin(idx)]     # filter dataframe

print(res)

    c  v
0  c1  5
1  c2  2
2  c1  7
6  c2  3
```

Answer (score 1):

by using `groupby` This can be achieved as below:

```
mask = df.groupby('c').count().reset_index()
mask = mask.loc[mask['v'] < 2]
res = df[~df.c.isin(mask.c.values)]
print(res)
```

output:

```
    c  v
0  c1  5
1  c2  2
2  c1  7
6  c2  3
```